# How do I find out how many connected clients there are to a HTTP Server in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, http

Let's say I'm running an app, that uses Express and Socket.io both listening on the same instance of a Node [`http.Server`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server).

Every second I want to log to the console the total number of connected clients (either HTTP or WS) for monitoring purposes.

```
setInterval(logConnectedClientInfo, 1000);
```

How can I implement the method `logConnectedClientInfo()`?

---

I know I could just do this by `exec`ing `lsof` but I'm interested if there's a way to do it in *Node*?

Comment: Do you mean online clients ?

Comment: Yes. How many open connections are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. The `net` module has a method on a server called [`server.getConnections()`](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_getconnections_callback). A `http.Server` in Node (0.10.30) inherits from `net.Server`. See `lib/_http_server.js` in node core:

```
util.inherits(Server, net.Server);
```

So my method would look like:

```
function logConnectedClientInfo() {
    server.getConnections(function(err, count){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(count);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

will this work ?

```
server.on('connection', function (socket) {
    activeConnections++;

    socket.on('end', function() {
        activeConnections--;
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I think this would work but I wanted to avoid maintaining that state if Node is already exposing a way to get at it from the standard library. Upvoted you though!

Comment: yes...  server.getConnections  is much better way of doing it - Thanks

Comment: Note that this method won't work correctly if server is running on `cluster` with multiple workers.